# uploading two images simultaneously and in one row php pdo

Tags: php, jquery, database, image, pdo

```
<form method="POST" action="crud.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<div style="background-color:#252323; color:#FFFFFF; "><b>Image Gallery</b></div>
<table>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="description">Big Image</label>
</td>
<td valign="top" style="text-align:right">
<input type="file" name="image" /></br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="description">Thumbnail Image</label>
</td>
<td valign="top" style="text-align:right">
<input type="file" name="image" /></br>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input id="button" type="submit" value="Add" name="imagegalleryadd"/>
</form>
```

This is my form it has two upload images with one button i want to upload two images at the same time and put them in two separate column in the datase because i will use these two images in a slider one for big image and other for thumbnail i tried upload only one images and it was good but how do you upload two images at the same time this is my code for adding images. This code only uploads one images how can it be changed to upload two?

```
function AddImageGallery(){
global $dbh;
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]['tmp_name'])){ 
        $folder = "images/imagegallery/"; 
        $file = basename( $_FILES['image']['name']); 
        $full_path = $folder.$file; 
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $full_path)) {
            echo "succesful upload, we have an image!";
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO imagegallery (imggall_imageurl) VALUES (?)");
            $stmt->bindValue(1,$full_path,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            if($stmt->execute()){
                echo "Image Recorded";
            }else{
                echo "Image was not Recorded";
            }

        } else { 
           echo "upload received! but process failed";

        } 
    }else{ 
        echo "upload failure ! Nothing was uploaded";
    }   
}
```

database will look like this

```
$sql ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $imagegallery ( 
        imggall_id int(40) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        imggall_imageurl VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL, 
        imggall_thumnailurl VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL);" ;
        $dbh->exec($sql);
```

`UPDATE`

new code i tried

```
function AddImageGallery(){
    global $dbh;
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["bigimage"]['tmp_name'] && $_FILES["thumbnailimage"]['tmp_name'] )){ 
        $folder = "images/imagegallery/"; 
        $filebi = basename( $_FILES['bigimage']['name']); 
        $fileti = basename( $_FILES['thumbnailimage']['name']); 
        $fileti = basename( $_FILES['thumbnailimage']['name']); 
        $fullbi_path = $folder.$filebi; 
        $fullti_path = $folder.$fileti; 
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['bigimage']['tmp_name'], $fullbi_path && $_FILES['thumbnailimage']['tmp_name'], $fullti_path )) {
            echo "succesful upload, we have an image!";
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO imagegallery (imggall_imageurl,imggall_thumnailurl) VALUES (?,?)");
            $stmt->bindValue(1,$fullbi_path,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(2,$fullti_path,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            if($stmt->execute()){
                header("Location: dashboard.php");
                exit;
                echo "Image Recorded";
            }else{
                echo "Image was not Recorded";
            }
        } else { 
           echo "upload received! but process failed";

        } 
    }else{ 
        echo "upload failure ! Nothing was uploaded";
    }   
}



<form method="POST" action="crud.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<div style="background-color:#252323; color:#FFFFFF; "><b>Image Gallery</b></div>
<table>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="description">Big Image</label>
</td>
<td valign="top" style="text-align:right">
<input type="file" name="bigimage" /></br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="description">Thumbnail Image</label>
</td>
<td valign="top" style="text-align:right">
<input type="file" name="thumbnailimage" /></br>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input id="button" type="submit" value="Add" name="imagegalleryadd"/>
</form>
```

Comment: `$_FILE['user']` not `$_FILES['image']['name']` to upload 2 use `foreach($_FILE['user'] as $img)`

Comment: update the question sorry for wrong info i was trying different approach i forgot to change it to original code...please be more specific with answer now that i updated the question

Comment: no you cant use same input name for two fields, instead use `<input type="file" name="image[]" />`

Comment: how will i save it into 1 row in database?if i use it like that it will save in two row right?

Answer (score 0):

Quick Google:

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php#53240

Shows a clear and simple method for multiple image uploads.

Quote:

```
function reArrayFiles(&$file_post) {

    $file_ary = array();
    $file_count = count($file_post['name']);
    $file_keys = array_keys($file_post);

    for ($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
        foreach ($file_keys as $key) {
            $file_ary[$i][$key] = $file_post[$key][$i];
        }
    }

    return $file_ary;
}

if ($_FILES['upload']) {
    $file_ary = reArrayFiles($_FILES['ufile']);

    foreach ($file_ary as $file) {
        print 'File Name: ' . $file['name'];
        print 'File Type: ' . $file['type'];
        print 'File Size: ' . $file['size'];
    }
}
```

For you:

```
<form method="POST" action="crud.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <input type="file" name="image[]" />
  <input type="file" name="image[]" />
  <input id="button" type="submit" value="Add" name="imagegalleryadd"/>
</form>
```

Then using the earlier function linked

```
if ($_FILES['upload']) {
    $file_ary = reArrayFiles($_FILES['ufile']);

    $main = $file_ary[0]['name'];
    $thumb = $file_ary[1]['name'];
    // Upload to DB 
}
```

Comment: please read question the way your link upload is not the same as question it will upload multiple question but with different id different row what i want is 1 id and 1 row please read carefully..

Comment: That is up to you and how you structure your database. columns: id, img1, img2.
Simply upload $file_ary[0] and $file_ary[1] to each img column as explained in the users post.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what exactly it is that you want.

Comment: i have two upload button each with have same image but different size one for big image one for thumbnail now i want to save two images at the same time in one row so i can use them together in slider..

Comment: So it's the exact same image, and you have 2 different buttons, 1 for each image? Why not just resize the image in php, or simply just give the image a width and height in css?

Comment: if i do that it will be distorted pixelized so i need to save two image so the image will look good

Comment: Okay, so why do you need 2 submit buttons, as opposed to 1 button uploading both?

Comment: how can you upload 2 images with just i button?

Comment: Maybe you can upload one image and resize it with php?

Comment: @MarcBouvier i already tried it but it will be distorted pixelized so not a good idea

Comment: If you can help me out here @JamesLalor would be so appreciated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304446/upload-multiple-images-to-seperate-database-columns-in-one-row

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="POST" action="crud.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<div style="background-color:#252323; color:#FFFFFF; "><b>Image Gallery</b></div>
<table>
    <tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <label for="description">Big Image </label>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <input type="file" name="bigimage" /></br>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <label for="description">Thumbnail Image </label>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <input type="file" name="thumbnailimage" /></br>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
        <input id="button" type="submit" value="Add" name="imagegalleryadd"/>
    </form>    

function AddImageGallery(){
        global $dbh;
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["bigimage"]['tmp_name'] )){ 
            $folder = "images/imagegallery/"; 
            $filebi = basename( $_FILES['bigimage']['name']); 
            $fileti = basename( $_FILES['thumbnailimage']['name']); 
            $fileti = basename( $_FILES['thumbnailimage']['name']); 
            $fullbi_path = $folder.$filebi; 
            $fullti_path = $folder.$fileti; 
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['bigimage']['tmp_name'], $fullbi_path)) {
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['thumbnailimage']['tmp_name'], $fullti_path )) {
                echo "succesful upload, we have an image!";
                $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO imagegallery (imggall_imageurl,imggall_thumnailurl) VALUES (?,?)");
                $stmt->bindValue(1,$fullbi_path,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindValue(2,$fullti_path,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                if($stmt->execute()){
                    header("Location: dashboard.php");
                    exit;
                    echo "Image Recorded";
                }else{
                    echo "Image was not Recorded";
                }
                }
            } else { 
               echo "upload received! but process failed";

            } 
        }else{ 
            echo "upload failure ! Nothing was uploaded";
        }   
    }
```

anyone can try this out i was able to get what

Answer (score 0):

If one is having difficulties with sending more than 1 image to .php it is crucial to put [] in the end of your name of input.
Thought I should mention that sine I spend last few hours wondering why PHP is not detecting more than 1 file.